# MySQL permits setting a foreign key constraint that references only one column of a composite primary key

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key

In the database structure depicted in the diagram that follows

[image]

the columns `key1` & `key2` make up the composite primary key of `table4`, but in `table3` I'm able to set up a foreign key constraint that makes a reference to `key1` only.

Why does MySQL allow this? Does the above database structure make no sense at all?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB allows a foreign key constraint to reference a non-unique key. This is an InnoDB extension to standard SQL.

Although this may come as a surprise, it is "documented behaviour".  This is probably one of these cases where you/we must just accept that things have been implemented in a certain manner ie InnoDB have implemented foreign keys this way.

Whether the design (in question) makes sense or not depends on the underlying business rules.  There may well be situations that require such a constraint.

Comment: And in another part of the docs ([`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)): *"Additionally, MySQL requires that the referenced columns be indexed for performance reasons. However, the system does not enforce a requirement that the referenced columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT NULL. The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE (including PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys."*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that InnoDB's semantics for a Foreign Key Constraint is simply "does this value exist in that table".  Hence, non-unique and first-of-composite fit ok.